# If statement only running once within for loop

Tags: php

So I've got a `.txt` file on the server that contains lines, the lines contain things like names of a file, which category that file is located in and the exact path to that file. I'm running a `for` loop that iterates through each line and stores the filename into it's own index in an array, the category, the exact path, and I'm also trying to read the `filesize()` of those files based on their given path.

I'm aware that in order to use `filesize()` you first need to check `if (file_exists())`, which I do in an `if` statement within the `for` loop.

Here's my loop:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $content["lines"]; $x++) {
    $content["packages"][$x]["name"] = strtok($content["eachLine"][$x], ".");
    $content["packages"][$x]["category"] = get_string_between($content["eachLine"][$x], ':', '^');
    $content["packages"][$x]["path"] = get_string_between($content["eachLine"][$x], '^', ';');
    if (file_exists("/var/www/public_html" . $content["packages"][$x]["path"])) {
        $content["packages"][$x]["size"] = filesize("/var/www/public_html" . $content["packages"][$x]["path"]);
    }
}
```

Some context info; `$content["lines"]` is an `int` equal to `2`, so the loop stops when it's supposed to, no issues there. The issue is that one the first iteration of the loop, it checks `if (file_exists())` and the string (file) given is from the first line in the file, since it does exist it then grabs the `filesize`. But on the 2nd iteration around the loop, it skips over that `if` statement entirely.

Here's an image of `var_dump($contents);`
[image]

I'm honestly super stumped here and have also look at other similar questions posted here on SO with no avail.

Comment: Don't know he rest of the script so can't say, but maybe hit [clearstratcache](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)? `file_exists()`: `The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.`

Comment: Code can't skip over if statements. So it is definitely running. You should check what files_exists() is returning and print the results.

Comment: What do you mean with "it skips over that if"?

Comment: @Emeeus He meant that it should be getting triggered true, but it's not. The if statement is getting triggered, but is returning false clearly, hence it's not running.

Comment: Something that evaluates to false! no `===`. `Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB. `

Comment: @ficuscr That seemed to do the trick! After the `if` statement, but still within the loop I put `clearstatcache();` and it did the trick. Is there something I can edit with `php.ini` to increase the cache size or any other way to circumvent that?

Comment: @Brian, No. No way to turn it off. I suggest reading the first two paragraphs on man page for `clearstatcache`. Not knowing rest of your code there hard to answer. lol...https://lyte.id.au/2014/05/01/what-the-hell-php/

Comment: Maybe an alternative could be fopen(the file) and evaluate the pointer.

Comment: You could just call `filesize()` without checking first. If the file doesn't exist, it will return `FALSE`. So check for this before assigning to the `size` element.

Comment: @Barmar When I call `filesize()` without checking if it exists first it always evaluates to false.

Comment: You're saying it returns false even if the file actually exists? I don't believe you. The documentation of `clearstatcache()` says: **PHP doesn't cache information about non-existent files.**

Comment: Sorry guys, my error lies within the `get_string_between()` function. I was check for a string between two characters that weren't in the string. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I feel silly. My error was with my "delimiters" in `get_string_between()`, the file `packages.txt` was using something other than `^` and `;`